# Carregar componente de forma dinâmica

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-6

Como faço para carregar um componente dinâmico dependendo do módulo que estou a ver em Angular?

Quero ter uma barra lateral que vai mostrar conteúdo conforme o módulo.

Por exemplo: Se estiver a ver o módulo Utilizadores quero ver a lista de utilizadores mais ativos, se estiver a ver o modulo de Artigos quero ver os artigos mais vendidos e com melhor avaliação.

Mas quero fazer isto da forma mais genérica possível, algo parecido com um interface em que obriga o componente do módulo implementar esse interface.